# How to continue raycast if the hit is not what we want without layermasks unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making tower defense game and to avoid enemies going through each other, I use a raycast to determine the distance between them. For now, everything works fine, but I want to make faster enemies able to go through the slower (so only check the distance for similar enemies). The problem is that I have more enemies types than layers and enemies are all in the same path (so raycast is often intercepted by the wrong enemy and then stops. I want to find a way to make it go through).

Situation example :

enemy 1 --- enemy 2 --- enemy 3

enemy1 shoots a ray to calculate the distance between him and enemy3, but the ray is intercepted by enemy2.

How do I make ray go through enemy2 if the enemy that fires it is not the same type ?

I hope my problem is clear enough, if not please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ruzihm isn't it a bit overkilled ? I mean some levels have a lot of enemies, so each of them raycasting all of them isn't optimal (I  think, I am not sure).

Comment: What does "not the same type" mean here?

Comment: @derHugo like an other enemy unit (for example there is slow armored enemies and fast small enemies, that is 2 different enemies type)

Comment: yeah but my question is rather: do these types change at runtime? Are they different class types or just different settings? etc

Comment: @derHugo they don't change at runtime and they are different class type. Anyway, I managed to do some work with VPellen 's solution and it seems to work.

Comment: Which is basically exactly whyt @Ruzihm linked isn't it? ;)

Comment: @derHugo yeah, but I thought there would be an other way. Anyway thanks for your help, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2D Physics, `Physics2D.Raycast` has multiple overloads, some of which take an array or a list of `RaycastHit2D` as a parameter which the function will promptly fill.

For 3D Physics, `Physics.RaycastAll` will return an array of `RaycastHit`. Note that the results of this function won't be in order, so you may want to sort the resulting list by distance from the ray origin.

Actually, upon closer inspection, there's also a `Physics2D.RaycastAll` that I didn't know about. I've been using the overloads of `Physics2D.Raycast` all this time. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that too much to raycast all (performance-wise) ? Because each enemy will do the raycast all...

Comment: Your options are going to either be RaycastAll, or your own algorithm which is ostensibly going to be a slower and more clumsy implementation of RaycastAll. Honestly, if it were me, I'd use layers, but I don't know the exact scope of your problem, and you explicitly said "without layer masks", so RaycastAll is probably your best option given those criteria.

Comment: Okay I will try that, thanks a lot for your help.